# Is setting element.id as a side effect bad practice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm writing a little cached function in a plugin / library. It takes a `HTMLElement` and returns a Decorator.

```
return function _cache(elem) {
    if (elem.id === "") {
        elem.id = PLUGIN_NAME + "_" + uid++;
    }
    if (cache[elem.id] === void 0) {
        cache[elem.id] = _factory(elem);
    }
    return cache[elem.id];
}
```

Here I'm storing some expensive operation in a cache by the `id` of the `HTMLElement`. This is a `O(1)` lookup but it uses the "bad practice" of setting `elem.id` and having a side effect.

The alternative would be `O(N)` lookup on the cache

```
return function _cache(elem) {
    for (var i = 0, ii = cache.length; i++) {
        var o = cache[i];
        if (o.elem == elem) return o.data;
    }
    var ret = _factory(elem);
    cache.push({ elem: elem, data: ret });
    return ret;
}
```

But this means that my cached expensive method doesn't have any side effects on the `HTMLElement`.

**Question:**

Is this "side effect" innocent and is it worth doing for the optimization on my decorator?

**Real Code:**

[Gist of plugin template where I use this snippet](https://gist.github.com/1013277)

**Edit:**

I'm clearly too tired and forgot `data-foo` exists. Here's how it should be implemented

```
var attr = "data-" + PLUGIN_NAME + "-cache";

return function _cache(elem) {
    var val = elem.getAttribute(attr);
    if (val === null || val === "") {
        val = PLUGIN_NAME +  "_" + uid++;
        elem.setAttribute(attr, val);
    }
    if (cache[val] === undefined) {
        cache[val] = _factory(elem);
    }
    return cache[val];
}
```

Comment: Well if it makes you feel better (or worse :-), jQuery does it sometimes.

Comment: Why insist upon setting the `id` property? (As opposed to a privately-named property.)

Comment: @pst I do not insist on it, I ask whether it is bad. I only set it, if it's not set. This increases the algorithm to `O(1)` instead of `O(N)`

Comment: @Raynos Why insist upon setting *the* `id` property?

Comment: @pst [example](http://jsfiddle.net/pyBX2/). Are properties set on `HTMLElement` going to be stored consistantly in a cross browser manner?

Comment: Personally I would use some kind of id/hashkey, but your question can easily be answered by building both versions and running performance tests - only you will know if it's too slow for its purpose.  Also due to ID being a commonly misused attribute (duplicates) a custom property wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @Raynos HTMLElement will accept arbitrary properties in all modern browsers I am aware of -- but I've only *verified* this for myself on IE8+ and FF3+; I'm not exactly sure if/where this is defined. Even in the case of a browser with "sealed" properties, `setAttribute` could be used (with it's own limitations).

Comment: @pst: `<object>`, `<applet>` and `<embed>` can't have "expando" properties, I remember reading in the jQuery source.  Not sure which browsers this applies to, but I can guess at least IE 8 and lower.  It's just a shame `WeakMap` won't arrive until ES 6.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using the `id`, use `data-x` - that's what it was created for.

`id` has a specific meaning, is confusing to see it automagically generated (even if properly documented, which is nearly never.) You're also risking a slight chance of override.

Comment: If you're *dynamically* adding attributes, I don't think there's much point in using "data-x" attributes *unless* there's some need/desire to be able to code values into the source. In that case, yes; otherwise, it's perfectly fine but not (in my opinion) any better than any other (reasonably "safe") attribute name.

Comment: @Pointy well if your going to pick any arbitrary "safe" attribute name it might as well be part of the semantic HTML5 data attributes. I agree any will do, but you might as well use data-x (the html5 buzz and all

Comment: To each his own :-)  Personally, my feeling is that once the browser has parsed my HTML5 *source*, whether or not the DOM subsequently retains any compliance with the spec is unimportant - at that point, it's the W3C DOM spec that matters, not the source language spec.  But that's just my opinion.  There's certainly nothing bad about using a "data-" prefix. In fact I'll vote it up!

Answer (score 4):

> Is this "side effect" innocent

No, clearly. Is it going to interact well with other scripts on the page? Don't know... that depends what it's for and what other kinds of scripts you expect it to be combined with. You can never make a ‘plugin’ that won't ever fail when interacting with other plugins and scripts, but by keeping the side-effects to a minimum you can at least try to minimise it.

Note that `id` is not a unique identifier. Although there should be only one element with a given ID in a document at one particular time, (a) multiple elements might be created with the same ID and inserted into the document sequentially (perhaps one element replacing another with the same ID), and (b) people still do use duplicate IDs even though it's wrong. Either would cause your cache to collect old, no-longer-used elements and return them inappropriately.

It is unfortunate that there is no JavaScript function to get a scalar/hashable unique identifier for an arbitrary object; the only way to obtain object identity is to `===`-compare against other objects.

Another common way forward is to add an arbitrary new property to the node (‘expando’ in IE terms), with a randomised really-unique ID. Expandos aren't guaranteed by standard to work, but it has worked in all browsers back to day one and is commonly used.

This is how for example jQuery identifies elements uniquely, and if you are writing a plugin for jQuery you might try taking advantage of that—`jQuery.expando` holds the name of the arbitrary expando property being used for this purpose... or, sticking within the documented featureset, `data()` could be used to add your own metadata to the element including another unique ID of your own.

Expandos do have some unpleasant side-effects including accidentally treating them as attributes in IE<9 (which can't tell the difference between properties and attribute), but if you're using jQuery anyway you probably don't have anything to lose.

> is it worth doing for the optimization on my decorator?

Depends how many you're expecting to have on a page. Comparing each item to each other item is an O(*n*²) operation; tolerable (and probably preferable given the side-effects) if *n* is low, but quickly getting unmanageable as *n* grows.

Comment: Oh man! An answer from the legendary bobince himself. I am blessed. `</ego boosting>`. I think using my `data-` to store a hashkey takes it down to O(1) in terms of getting it out of the cache.

Comment: Yes, it's essentially the same as the expando approach except working on an attribute instead of a property or `data()`. Upside: no ugly expando; downside: the potential unwanted interaction is that some other script changes the attribute or clones the element, copying the attribute onto another object. I'm still scratching my head at ‘legendary’...

Comment: how do I gaurd againts someone copying an element with the attribute identifying that element as being in the cache?

Comment: You can't stop it! You *might* fare better with jQuery's `data()`, in that `.clone()` doesn't copy the data (except in jQuery 1.5.0... sigh). But still, some non-jQuery script could come along and clone, mess with the attribute or hack the `innerHTML` in such a way as to duplicate or remove the jQuery expando. There is no foolproof solution, alas.

Comment: The ‘proper’ DOM way to do this, with handlers that are guaranteed to get called back on clone operations, would be DOM Level 3 Core's `getUserData`/`setUserData` interface. However, browser support for this is poor: currently only Firefox has it.